# How can I use Subversion command line client to tell me what I committed today (or this week, month)?

Tags: svn

Is there a `svn` subcommand that can tell me what commits I have made during a period or since a certain time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try

```
svn log -r {2010-08-01}:{2010-08-31}
```

which would give you the current month's commits.  I don't know of an option to filter by user so would just pipe the output to grep.

```
svn log -r {2010-08-01}:{2010-08-31} | grep myName
```

That seemed to work pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn log -r {2006-02-17}
```

Will give you all the commits since the specified date.

You can see the specs of the revision date format [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates).

Comment: Beat me to it - although I think he may need by user as well.

Comment: Doesn't that just give you the last commit for that time?

Comment: it will give you the commits from that time until now.